# Mildly context-sensitive grammar

Tags: context-free, context-sensitive

Consider a context-sensitive grammar $G$, such that all the productions of $G$ have the form $A\to \alpha$ or $Ab \to \alpha b$ (in other words, the left context is always empty and the right context is either empty or consists of just one terminal).

Is the language defined by such a grammar necessarily context-free ?

In all the toy examples I considered, the original context-sensitive grammar can be enlarged into an equivalent context-free one.

Comment: Penttonen normal form has productions $A \to a$, $A \to BC$, and $AB \to AC$. Your productions are however less powerful.

Comment: Theorem 1 [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0201003) seems to imply that your grammars generate context-free languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have written a paper based on your discovery had you been researching this problem many years ago.

In fact, the paper [*Terminal Context in Context-Sensitive Grammars* by Ronald V. Book, 1972](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0201003) mentioned by Yuval proved the following theorem, edited slightly for the sake of current question.

> Theorem 2. If $G$ is a context-sensitive grammar with terminals $\Sigma$, non-terminals $N$ such that every non-context-free rule is of the form $\alpha Z\beta \to \alpha\gamma \beta$ where $\alpha\in\Sigma^*$, $\beta\in\Sigma^*$ and $Z\in N$, then $L(G)$ is context-free.

The grammar in the question is the special case of the grammar in the theorem above where $\alpha$ is the empty string and $\beta$ is either the empty string or a terminal.

Check that paper for a proof of the theorem as well as more insight on how to force context-sensitive grammars to be context-free. (You can probably publish a paper if you could solve the conjecture at the end of that paper.)

---

Here is one exercise that is within easy reach.

**Exercise 1.** If $G$ is a context-free grammar except one rule, which is of form $Aa\to Ba$, where $a$ is a terminal and $A$ and $B$ are two non-terminals, then $L(G)$ is context-free.